# Closed set in topological product

Tags: general-topology

We know that $\Pi_{i=1}^{n} \overline{A_i}=\overline{A}$ where $A=\Pi_{i=1}^n A_i$

How we can see from this that $\Pi_{i=1}^n A_i$ i closed if and only if each $A_i$ is closed ?

thank you

Comment: Provided that all the $A_i$ are non-empty, or we have trivial counterexamples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is closed, then $\overline{A}=A$, so $\prod_{i=1}^n\overline{A_i}=\prod_{i=1}^nA_i$, so $\overline{A_i}=A_i$ for each $i$ (each component is closed).

If each $A_i$ is closed, then $\overline{A}=\prod_{i=1}^n\overline{A_i}=\prod_{i=1}^nA_i=A$, so $A$ is closed, too.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the projection map onto each component. Projection maps are closed maps.

Comment: Can you explain me more?

Comment: If each component is closed, their closures are just themselves. So the product is closed and therefore, it is its own closure.

Comment: If each $A_i$ is closed then using the adherence the product i closed but how to do the other sens ? if the product is closed how to see that each $A_i$ is closed ? thank you

Comment: That is what I stated in the answer.

Comment: the other sens we do projection ?? i don't understand how ?

Comment: The projection of a closed set onto each of its components is closed.

Comment: we can't see it juste by using the adherence ?

Comment: Projection maps are **open**, not closed. For instance, $$S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\,:\, xy=1\}$$ is closed, but $\pi_x(S)=\pi_y(S)=\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: Of course, not $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$, but $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Well then, looks like I messed up my last topology homework